# For any n and some prime p there is an elemnet in Zp* of order n

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I prove, that for any positive integer $n>0$ there is a prime $p$, such that the multiplicative group of the residue ring $Z_p^*$ contains an element $a$ of order $n$? No ideas at all...

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Start by investigating the case that n is prime, and look at factors of a^n - 1.  When you handle that, try n a prime power.  Gerhard "Eventually, Look Up Zsigmondy's Theorem" Paseman, 2013.06.19

Comment: Voted to close. 

Comment: Not research level, but also probably not homework. Please do not delete; there is information in the answer and in the comments which could be useful for mathematicians. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z_p^*$ is of order $p-1$ so what you are really asking is for a prime in the arithmetic progression $n+1, 2n+1, 3n+1, \ldots$.  This is true by Dirichlet's theorem, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Comment: More elementarily, the poster is asking for a (positive) integer b such that b^n - 1 is a multiple of some prime p while b^m - 1 is not such a multiple for m < n.  A proof by Bang was given for n > 6 (pick b=2) and for fixed b and n all the allowed cases were characterized by Zsigmondy.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.06.19

Comment: But I'm not sure that's the cleanest approach, Gerhard. I would agree that Dirichlet's theorem in its full statement (involving densities) is a sledgehammer, but the infinitude of primes in this arithmetic progression can be proven in very elementary fashion. See for example proposition 3, here: http://math.stanford.edu/~dlitt/exposnotes/primes1mod4.pdf 

Comment: I will agree that an approach involving arithmetic progressions like that does lead to a prime p with the desired property, and may be shorter if not cleaner than an approach involving Bang or Zsigmondy.  I interpret Katz's answer as saying that the "question behind the question" is about primes in such progressions; this intepretation I disagree with, and suggest for self study of this problem an alternative.  However, the poster has accepted Katz's answer; perhaps a proof more than understanding is wanted.  Gerhard "To Each Their Own Heaven" Paseman, 2013.06.24